# How to apply macro at end of every heading in MS Word?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a document with various headings (so not necessarily Heading 1 or Heading 2 - but all types of headings).

What I'm trying to do is write a macro that will, for example, delete 2 spaces at the end of each heading.

For example, we have

## This is a heading

At the end of heading, I will do:

```
Selection.Delete Unit:=wdCharacters, Count:=2
```

I need this to be applied at the end of each heading.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Goto first heading:

```
   Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToHeading,Which:=wdGoToFirst
```

Goto next heading

```
   Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToHeading,Which:=wdGoToNext
```

Check where you are to see if you have reached the last heading:

```
   x=Selection.Start
   Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToHeading,Which:=wdGoToNext
   if x = Selection.Start then '... last heading reachd
```

Goto end of current heading (for example, to delete chars:

```
   Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdLine
```