# How to jump to paragraphs with an outline level regardless of style in Word VBA?

Tags: vba, ms-word, word-2013

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1801334) asks about moving between headers in Word VBA, and Doc Brown kindly [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1956036/2877364) `Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToHeading`.  When I use

```
ActiveWindow.Selection.GoTo wdGoToHeading, wdGoToNext
```

or

```
ActiveWindow.Selection.GoTo wdGoToHeading, wdGoToPrevious
```

the selection moves between `Heading <n>` styles, but does not jump to custom styles I have created that have Outline levels of Level 1, 2, ... (not Body Text).  Other than repeatedly calling `Next wdParagraph` and testing for `Range.OutlineLevel < wdOutlineLevelBodyText`, is there any way to jump between paragraphs based on *outline level*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this by using Outline View to only show the Outline Levels that you're interested in, then navigate between the visible paragraphs:

```
ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.Type = wdOutlineView
ActiveWindow.View.ShowHeading 3
Selection.MoveDown Unit:=wdParagraph
```

Comment: Works nicely - thanks!  Unfortunately, even with `Application.ScreenUpdating=False`, it still flickers quite a bit when changing to Outline View, and then back to whatever view I was in before.  Do you happen to know if there's a way to suppress that?